# Java crop specific part of different resolution images

Tags: java, image, crop

I am looking to get a specific part of an image through java.
I have 11 images with different resolutions.

If we take [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONJzf.jpg) as an example image

I want to extract [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RPNu.png) part

Here's my code

```
try {
        BufferedImage originalImgage = ImageIO.read(new File("bin\\" + backImage[randNum]));                    

        BufferedImage SubImgage = originalImgage.getSubimage((originalImgage.getWidth()/2) - 340 , originalImgage.getHeight() - 70, 700, 70);                   
        System.out.println("" + (originalImgage.getWidth()/2 - 700));
        ImageIO.write(SubImgage, "png", new File("bin\\gauLock.png"));                                  

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

As you can see, the height is not a problem but the width is because of different resolutions

So my question is how can I obtain a specific part of all images

Comment: "As you can see, the height is not a problem" - It's not?  You're OK with getting 70 pixels no matter what the resolution is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about the amount of the image you want as a fraction of the whole image.  If you want the middle 50% of the image horizontally, this would work no matter the resolution:

```
    BufferedImage SubImgage = originalImgage.getSubimage((originalImgage.getWidth()/4), originalImgage.getHeight() - 70, originalImage.getWidth()/2, 70);
    System.out.println("" + (originalImgage.getWidth()/2 - 700));
```